# Parsing the first image src of a list

Tags: jquery

I need to parse a value from an xml and place it to image's src field.
I tried parsing it as `$(".photoBox img").append(ImageSmURL);`
and I got

```
<img src="" alt="">/FLPM/media/images/0E7Q9Z0C_sm.jpg/FLPM/media/images/2A9L1V2X_sm.jpg</img>
```

how do I do it so the result will be as...

```
<img src="/FLPM/media/images/0E7Q9Z0C_sm.jpg" alt="" />
```

My xml

```
<Images>
<ImageID id="63">
<ImageSmURL>/FLPM/media/images/5V2G4Q5S_sm.jpg</ImageSmURL>
<ImageLgURL>/FLPM/media/images/5V2G4Q5S.jpg</ImageLgURL>
</ImageID>
<ImageID id="64">
<ImageSmURL>/FLPM/media/images/5Y2K4T5V_sm.jpg</ImageSmURL>
<ImageLgURL>/FLPM/media/images/5Y2K4T5V.jpg</ImageLgURL>
</ImageID>
</Images>
```

Comment: var ImageSmURL = $(this).find('ImageSmURL').text();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
$(".photoBox img").attr("src", ImageSmURL);
```

[`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) adds text/elements at the end of an element.
[`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) sets the given attribute, in this case `src`.

Comment: hey this is great but there is still a  problem. My code still takes both ImageSmURL values from the xml file. So the result is as <img src="/FLPM/media/images/0E7Q9Z0C_sm.jpg/FLPM/media/images/2A9L1V2X_sm.jpg" alt="">

Comment: @zurna - You want to take the first one, or create an image each or...? What's the desired output?

Comment: @zurna - Use this selector in that case: `$(this).find('ImageSmURL:first').text();`